# How to avoid the user opening the same web page twice

Tags: asp.net

I thought maybe if I make like something the PTC page makes; that avoid to submit the same page twice.  I need for more idea to perform that. In asp.net for example.

Comment: Welcome to SO. How is this page opened? A link? A button?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to hide the button, linkbutton whatever it is when the user click it. This is the most easiest way in asp.net application. You can also disable it but what happens in that case the postback does not occur at all. So its better to hide it. If you dont want to hide it then procedure is bit tricky

E.g

```
<asp:button id="btn" runat="server" onclientclick="this.style.visibility='hidden';" />
```

Lengthy Process:

If you see the source of asp.net page it attach the events to buttons as

```
settimeout(__doPostback); etc etc...
```

So in out case we can disable the button too but with settimeout greater than the timeout specified by asp.net controls so after the user click it our function will be called and disable the buttons

Answer (score 0):

You can hide your link button after a single click event appeared in your form.
Please try the code below

**button code**

```
<asp:button id="btnName" runat="server" onclientclick="javascript:return disableButton()" OnClick="btnName_Click" />
```